# json.loads(request.body) gives "No JSON object could be decoded" error (Django)

Tags: json, django

I am building an app using Django with Django Rest Framework and AngularJS with CoffeScript. I am basing on the tutorial https://thinkster.io/brewer/angular-django-tutorial/. I have a problem with passing json from the client side, but I think that the problem is clearly in my view, because even posting json via DRF api gives the same error - "No JSON object could be decoded" caused by the line `data = json.loads(request.body)`.

My APIView is following (clearly the same as in the tutorial):

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if account is not None:
            if account.is_active:
                login(request, account)

                serialized = AccountSerializer(account)

                return Response(serialized.data)
            else:
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Unathorized',
                    'message': 'This account has been disabled.'
                }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNATHORIZED)
        else:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unathorized',
                'message': 'Username/password combination invalid.'
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNATHORIZED)
```

When I try to pass the JSON from api and try to print request.body in the console I have such a result:

`csrfmiddlewaretoken=s2dIiOy7eNUJJfGBRaDAFmJ632kjbokz&_content_type=application%2Fjson&_content=%7B%0D%0A%22email%22%3A+%22example@ex.com%22%2C%0D%0A%22password%22%3A+%22example%22%0D%0A%7`

It doesn't seem to be a correct JSON. Am I right that something is wrong in this view? Or should I look somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

```
    email = request.data.get('email', None)
    password = request.data.get('password', None)
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: The docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing

Answer (score -1):

You are not converting your response into actual JSON.

Example:

```
else:
    return Response(json.dumps({
        'status': 'Unathorized',
        'message': 'Username/password combination invalid.'
    }), status=status.HTTP_401_UNATHORIZED)
```

Comment: It's not failing on the response

Answer (score -1):

You haven't shown your JS code, but it seems that you're posting the data in form-encoded format and the JSON itself is in the `content` field. So you would get it like this:

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['content'])
```

Comment: The docs: django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing